# Manage multi-language with Algolia

Tags: reactjs, algolia

I am building a website with Remix + Algolia. I would like to support multi-languages including en and ja.

I use `react-instantsearch-hooks-web` to render the UI

How should I manage the localized documents in Algolia? Which approach is better?

**Approach 1: ** One index per language

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/optimize-search-results/handling-natural-languages-nlp/how-to/multilingual-search/#one-index-per-language

In this way, if I support many more languages (eg: 8), I need 8 indices which is a lot. I don't know if it's a problem but the code looks ugly

```
        // 8 indices
    const index = algoliaInstance.initIndex('docs_en');
    const jaIndex = algoliaInstance.initIndex('docs_en');
    const frIndex = algoliaInstance.initIndex('docs_fr');
    ...

        const settings = {
        searchableAttributes: [
            "title",
            "subtitle",
            "hostProviders",
            "industries",
            "company",
            "body",
        ],
    }

        // 8 indices
    index.setSettings(settings);
    jaIndex.setSettings(settings);
    frIndex.setSettings(settings);
```

**Approach 2: ** One index for all

Well, I just dump all the docs into one index. Just add an attribute called "lang" to the docs

Based on the url, I want to return the correct localized docs

```
/en/search => return en docs
/ja/search => return ja docs
```

How do I filter the search results by lang? Now the results return both "en" and "ja" and other languages.